# How can I detect hitbox in my pygame game and get an output for it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have here my code.

```
#Player Spawn
player = Player()  # spawn player
player.rect.y = 0  # go to y
player_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
player_list.add(player)


#Asteoriden spawn
enemy = Enemy()
enemy.rect.y = 150
enemy.rect.x = 1000
enemy_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
enemy_list.add(enemy)



running = True


while running:
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            pygame.quit()

        #more code


        for player in player_list:
            if player.rect.colliderect(enemy):
                print("hit")

    win.blit(bg, (0,0))
    player.update()
    enemy.update()
    enemy_list.draw(win)
    player_list.draw(win)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

The Player () and Enemy () are classes for my objects that should collide. But if I run the code now it will show a lot of 'hit' but I want only one 'hit' to be shown. My whole console is full of 'hit'. If I later want to replace the 'hit' with a function, it will run more often than it should.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the collisions in a list:

```py
collisions = []
```

Whenever an enemy hits a player, save a tuple of the enemy and the player in the list. Remove the tuple when the enemy and the player no longer hit. Just print "hit" (or invoke a function) when the enemy and player collide but the tuple of the player and the enemy isn't in the list yet. This means that the enemy and player just hit but didn't hit right before:

```py
while running:
    # [...]

    for enemy in enemy_list:
        for player in player_list:
        
            if player.rect.colliderect(enemy):
            
                if not (player, enemy) in collisions:
                    collisions.append((player, enemy))
                    print("hit") 
                    
            else:
               
                if (player, enemy) in collisions:
                    collisions.remove((player, enemy))

    # [...]
```